# How to edit an installed python xbee module library in Ubuntu

Tags: python, xbee

I have installed Xbee python module in Ubunto16.04, But I need to edit and add some code in one of its basic modules. it was suggested to download the source, edit desired files, and install it from source.
so I uninstalled last installed Xbee package, then I downloaded the source from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XBee#downloads and after extracting and editing desired files. used this command:

```
python setup.py install
```

but when I came back to run my code I got the message:

```
importError:No module named 'xbee'
```

how should I fix this?

Comment: did you use `sudo` with your installation command? in order to install and use package globally, you need root access in your installation.

Comment: @ParhamAlvani
yes, I did.

Comment: and did you use same python version for Xbee installation and running your code?

Comment: @ParhamAlvani sure, I used the same python version

Comment: did you try `build` before installation using `python setup.py build`?

Comment: @ParhamAlvani documentation didn't mention this but is uninstalled everything and did it from the beginning, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `xbee` library as project module instead of install, you need to download `XBee-2.3.1.tar.gz` and extract it. Directory contains module `xbee`, copy it to your root project and you can update code in it.